# Not able to make Service account call in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, service-accounts

I have multiple microservices configured for service accounts in Keycloak authorization server.
Now, I want to run a task on application load of client service. In this task, I will be making an API call to a protected resource on resource server.
Client service is already configured for service account.

Since I need to make this call on application load, I am using `@EventListener` with `ApplicationReadyEvent` event. So far its good. Now, to make an API call to resource server I need have access token. For this I see multiple ways suggested.
First I tried with `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` approach:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
    clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
            oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            oauthToken.getName());

String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

Here, second parameter to `loadAuthorizedClient` needs to be Principal name. But not sure what should be principal name for service account which is not related with any user login. If I give any random placeholder string, it fails to return access token.

Another approach is to inject `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` using `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient`:

```
@Configuration
public class StartupEventListener {
   
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;


    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient;


    public StartupEventListener(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("client1") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        this.authorizedClient = authorizedClient;
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

            OAuth2AccessToken token = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
            // After getting token, further logic to make API call should go here.
            

    }

}
```

Here it fails with following exception:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient(registrationId="", value="client1")}
```

To be sure, I am able to get access token through curl and make API call thereafter.

Appreciate any hints/directions on the above issue.
Thanks.